# Hibernate ManytoMany @JoinTable update issue

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am facing an issue when updating the many to many table. Save is working fine but not update. When updating, it deletes the old records but the new records are not getting inserted.

Just a brief intro about tables:

Parent Table - MainTable

Lk Table - LK (LK has FK_Type which is an another lookup)

ManytoMany - Test_Many

TEST_MANY Table has three columns:

1.FK_MAINID

2.FK_LK_ID

3.FK_LKTYPE

All three columns are PK of TEST_MANY. The second and third column are PK columns from LK table and the first column is PK column in Main Table.

Please find the code below.

Entity:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "TEST_MANY", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_MAINID", referencedColumnName = "PK_MAINID", nullable = false, updatable = false)},
        inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "FK_LKID", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "FK_LKTYPE", referencedColumnName = "FK_TYPE", nullable = false, updatable = false)}
)
private List<LK> lookups;
```

In DAO:

```
Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
MainTable maintable = (MainTable) session.get(MainTable.class, id);
maintable.getLookups().clear;
maintable.setLookups(lookups));
session.merge(maintable);
```

Any help appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: Does the setter `MainTable.setLookups()` reuse the collection which you previously cleared? Or does it assign the parameter to the field?

Comment: It doesnot reuse the collection previously cleared. I assign a new collection object to it.

Comment: Try reusing the collection. Afaik the collection object, provided by Hibernate when loading an entity, is some `PersistentCollection`, which is monitored in a session. So I suggest adding all elements to it instead of "throwing it away".

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the persistentcollection provided by Hibernate. I clear the contents so that it will delete all the rows and adding the new rows by using setters. Also, I have tried your suggestion reusing the collection as maintable.getLookups().addAll(lookups) but still not working.  Further debugging the code, I have created dummy lookup table with composite key but not a foreign key (to another lookup). That works fine. So I am wondering is the foreign key in the lookup table is the issue?

Comment: Can you provide a Maven project with all required classes and dependencies to reproduce the issue? The classes should only contain the information required to reproduce the behavior.

Comment: Are there any mappings on the inverse side?

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. The issue is resolved. The problem was not with the mapping but the `lookups` collection was null because of another issue.

Comment: Well, what issue? Please answer your question yourself to help others.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Brian and Dragan.

The issue is resolved. The problem was the collection `lookups` coming as null. So in the update function:

```
 Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
 MainTable maintable = (MainTable) session.get(MainTable.class, id);
 maintable.getLookups().clear;
 maintable.setLookups(lookups));
 session.merge(maintable);
```

First clearing the rows as expected. Then setting null won't create any rows.

Thank you guys for all your suggestions.